# SQL statement to validate if two values are NULL

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, null

Right now I have a sql statement in my website that checks if an active value is NULL in my database in order for users to login.  I implemented a secondary activation method and I now have two active fields: active and active2.  Below is my sql statement that works currently however I need to it to reflect two fields now.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND active IS NULL";
```

I tried CONCAT but I don't think that is the right syntax as it doesn't seem to work.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND CONCAT(active, active2) IS NULL";
```

I need to check both active and active2 fields in my sql statement to see if they are null, if they are null then the user can sign in, right now its only checking the first active field.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is wrong with  `... AND active IS NULL AND active2 IS NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be:

> $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND
>   (active IS null) AND (active2 IS NULL)";

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `COALESCE()`

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND COALESCE(active, active2, NULL) IS NULL";
```